# How to stop systemd from spamming rsyslog in CentOS 7

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I've followed the instructions in this [Redhat Bugfix article](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=727315), that is I did the following (I realize this is a Redhat fix)

- Create a /etc/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service file
- put the following lines in the file

  .include /lib/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service
  [Service]
  Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=warning
- Restarted the rsyslog and systemd-logind services

Yet I still see systemd logs spamming /var/log/messages. Anything else I need to do in a CentOS box? Here's a sample

```
<30>1 2016-08-23T13:09:48-04:00 susralcent09 systemd - - -  Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
<30>1 2016-08-23T12:48:37-04:00 susralcent09 systemd - - -  Started System Logging Service.
<30>1 2016-08-23T12:48:36-04:00 susralcent09 systemd - - -  Stopping System Logging Service...
<30>1 2016-08-23T12:48:36-04:00 susralcent09 systemd - - -  Starting System Logging Service...
```

...and

```
<30>1 2016-08-23T13:01:01-04:00 susralcent09 systemd - - -  Created slice user-0.slice.
<30>1 2016-08-23T13:01:01-04:00 susralcent09 systemd - - -  Started Session 2 of user root.
<30>1 2016-08-23T13:09:48-04:00 susralcent09 systemd - - -  Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
<30>1 2016-08-23T13:01:01-04:00 susralcent09 systemd - - -  Starting Session 2 of user root.
<30>1 2016-08-23T13:01:01-04:00 susralcent09 systemd - - -  Starting user-0.slice.
```

Comment: Can you add some lines  from /var/log/messages

Comment: What do you mean "add some lines?" I see it growing yes, with systemd messages.

Comment: Add to description of your question :)

Comment: @AstraSerg. Got ya! I "added some lines" now. :)

Comment: Maybe `echo 'ForwardToSyslog=no' >> /etc/systemd/journald.conf && systemctl restart systemd-journald` will help...

Comment: @AstraSerg Thanks, but the conf file change didn't help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121659/discussion-between-chris-f-and-astraserg).